# Apache Rewrite rule to replace underscore with hyphen and append extension at end

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need help to create apache rewrite rule. My requirement is as given below.

Source URL: "http://localhost/directory/file_name_1"

Destination URL: "http://localhost/file-name-1.html"

Note: Above requirement is not for static URL, but there would be any other word instead of "directory" and "file_name_1".

- "directory" word should be removed in new redirected URL
- underscore ( _ ) should be replaced with Hyphen ( - )
- "file-name-1" should be ended with .html extension.

I appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below rules and now it is working.

```
    RewriteEngine    On
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$
    RewriteRule     .*    - [S=3]
    RewriteRule     ^(/?.*/[^/]*?)_([^/]*?_[^/]*)$ $1-$2 [N]
    RewriteRule     ^(/?.*/[^/]*?)_([^/_]*)$ $1-$2.html  [NC]
    RewriteRule     ^/(.*)/(.*)$        $2               [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/?.*/[^/]*?)_([^/]*?_[^/]*)$ $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(/?.*/[^/]*?)_([^/_]*)$ $1-$2 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiy. How do I append extension at end of URL.

Comment: Thanks sergiy. It was working. But it just redirect from "_" to "-". How we can rewrite it. Is there any thing else we need to put in my .htaccess file.?