# 301 Redirects Rewrite Rule to replace underscore with hyphen and remove subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help creating a rewrite rule/301 redirect for the following link structures in the .httaccess folder.

Source URL: www.example.com/sub_directory/product_name_1.html

Destination URL: www.example.com/prodcut-name-1.html

The requirements for the redirect then are as follows:

- Remove /sub_directory/
- Change all underscores '_' to hyphens '-'

Unfortunately my regex isn't very good. I've tried searching around and but the solutions from other post with similar issues where not working for me (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190407/apache-rewrite-rule-to-replace-underscore-with-hyphen-and-append-extension-at-en))

Any help on a solution for this would be much appreciated. Also if you could please explain the why/how of it. I'd like to be able to better understand this.

Comment: Do you already have some code in `sub_directory/.htaccess`?

Comment: This is for the .htaccess in the root. The site was transferred over to a new platform and that directory no longer exist. The page structure changed as i described above. I'm just redirecting all links that went to that sub directory to the main products page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer from @Walf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755682/548225) is close but requires some changes e.g. regex anchors and `DPI` flag.

You can use these rules on **top of your site root .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove /sub_directory/ when there is no _ left
RewriteRule ^sub_directory/([^_]+)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]

# use recursion based rule to replace _ by -
RewriteRule ^(sub_directory/[^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [NC,N,DPI]

# rest of your rules go here
```

Comment: You're welcome. Didn't think to comment on/improve my answer?

Comment: @Walf, I tried your answer but couldn't make it work. However my apologies that I should have given you credit for the regex and whole approach (upvtoted now)

Comment: Good etiquette is to write whose answer you've built on in your answer.

Comment: Have edited answer with a reference to your answer. Please also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40001902/548225)

Comment: The `DPI` flag was missing in my rules and this saved me!!! Couldn't figure out why it wasn't working before that...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(sub_directory/[^_]*)_+(.*) $1-$2 [DPI,N]
RewriteRule ^sub_directory(?:$|/(.*)) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It first loops through URLs that are in that subdirectory, to replace consecutive underscores with a single hyphen. It's done first so it doesn't interfere with other URLs that may contain an underscore. It then externally redirects (the cleaned) requests for that subdirectory to the root. The ugly grouping makes sure it only applies to exactly that folder.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this didn't work. The URLs are remaining unchanged. Attempting to just change all underscores to hyphens had no effect either. Perhaps another rule we have in place is interfering. 

We are just going to redirect all request to this sub domain to the main products page. Thank you again.